# Google Colab: cuBLAS, cuFFT, and cuDNN factory registration warnings

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, huggingface, large-language-model

I was playing around with Wizard-Vicuna in colab. I tried the 13B model and the other day it was working fine. I can change the prompts and it would generate alright. However, yesterday when I tried playing with it again, the session would start crashing. For reference I did not change anything from my [colab code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lX4gX7FyrbfXXvg7lz7SWOyiJ9_RAldJ#scrollTo=1Y_3DfNE3VSa) except I downgraded to the 7B model for faster testing.

I looked at the app.log and here are what I got:

```
2023-11-04 06:48:44.105742: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered

2023-11-04 06:48:44.106486: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered

2023-11-04 06:48:44.106982: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered

2023-11-04 06:48:45.782701: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
```

I made sure I was running on T4 GPU and I tried resetting the runtime as well. I tried some solutions from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62075) but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.